# how to check google analytics code fired through python

Tags: javascript, python, google-analytics, automation, google-tag-manager

I have a website on which Google Analytics code fires (through Google Tag Manager). The site has a lot of pages and I want to check if Google Analytics code fires on all pages. One way would be to open the URL, open GA debugger and check the pageview firing in the console.
Since there are a lot of URLs which need to be checked, is there a way to automate this process (preferably by Python)

Edit:

1. What I've tried so far:
   I've managed to get the fetch the source code of the pages and then regexing my way to find specific code snippets (of GA and GTM) You can find the code [here](https://github.com/yalk/GTM-TagChecker). But the problem is this will fetch just the static code. Any pixels/codes firing after the page actually loads will not be captured.
2. The issue with using Selenium is that I will be performing this test for possibly thousands of URLs. Selenium will slow the process down considerably.

Comment: Hey Ankur, could you possibly [edit] to show something you've tried so far that didn't quite work the way you wanted?  Having *some* code to show will help others help you.

Comment: There are testing frameworks (Selenium, Casper etc.) that can be scripted via python (amongst other languages) that can catch the http responses send by GA. Maybe you want to investigate something like this and then get back with specific problems, as is stands the question is rather broad.